# Save dialog opens when trying to debug

Tags: c#

Save dialog opens and asks me to save one of my classes when I try to debug my program, if close the dialog nothing happens, if I press save it will say "Access to *filepath to class* is denied" and it wont debug. If I simply remove the class that causes the problem and copy paste its code into a new class with the same name it works for some time but as soon as I add significantly more code to that class the same problem occurs, I am clueless of what to do about it, thankful for any ideas. Probably worth mentioning is that it's a team project, using teamfoundation source controll, might have something to do with that but not sure.

Comment: and the name of the class is?

Comment: Component.cs, but does it make any difference?